# C++: Why does this constexpr template function cause an internal error in VS2017?(In gcc is ok)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, gcc, constexpr

This code compiles fine in GCC, but it causes an ***internal*** error in Visual Studio 2017 compiler. What is wrong in my code? Or it is an compiler issue? I`ve heard that VS doesnt use two phase name lookup and this can cause problems in some cases.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto doSomeSum(const T* a, const T* b) {
    if (a > b)return 0;
    auto sum = 0;
    while (a != b)
        sum += *(a++);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0b1000,9,10 };
    constexpr float second[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    constexpr auto a = doSomeSum<int>(arr, arr+10);
    constexpr auto b = doSomeSum<float>(second,second+10); //works if I comment this line
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you explicitly declare `sum` as `T` or as `std::decay_t<T>`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, and least insofar as the compiler internal error is concerned. Nothing you could possibly write in C++ should result in your compiler barfing like that. An internal compiler error is always a compiler bug. File a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: @Xirema, explicit declaration of type does not help and `std::decay_t` too

Comment: There is a 2017.1 update.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There's actually a very subtle bug, albeit one that's really easy to miss; out of Clang, GCC, and MSVC, MSVC appears to be the only one that actually hints at it without any special testing.  Clang will fail to compile the code, and GCC will deduce `main()::b`'s type as `int`, due to type deduction in `doSomeSum()`; specifically, it deduces both the return type and `sum`'s type as `decltype(0)`, which is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue (which also occurs with MSVC 2015) appears to be that it deduces both the return type and `sum`'s type as `int`, then has an aneurysm whenever `T` is a different type.  I'm not sure about 2017, but 2015 emits this warning before it implodes:

> main.cpp(6): warning C4244: '+=': conversion from 'const float' to 'int', possible loss of data
>   main.cpp(15): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int doSomeSum(const T *,const T *)' being compiled
>           with
>
> ```
>     [
>         T=float
>     ]
> ```

Where line 6 is:

```
    sum += *(a++);
```

Therefore, it sees `*(a++)` as `const float`, but `sum` as `int`; this is because `sum` is initialised with `0`, an integer literal.  We can easily fix this, however, by instead initialising it with `T{0}`, tying `sum`'s type to the template parameter.  As this will cause return type deduction to determine two conflicting types (`int` for `0`, `T` for `sum`), we must also change the first line to return `T{0}`.  And thus, the end result is:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto doSomeSum(const T* a, const T* b) {
    if (a > b)return T{0};
    auto sum = T{0};
    while (a != b)
        sum += *(a++);
    return sum;
}
```

<sub>Tested with [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/C7rRJt) and [RiSE4Fun's MSVC 2015 online environment](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) (note that the latter doesn't provide any facility to link to individual sessions).  Testing the original code with [GCC and Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a3bbd09a6250ba3) demonstrates that both have the same issue, with Clang also emitting an error due to it.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this solution works) It was because compiler could not deduce return type of this function.

Comment: @EgorKhromov You're welcome.  It can also be prevented by not marking `main()::b` as `constexpr`, but that doesn't solve the underlying issue.  It's not that it couldn't deduce the return type, though; it could deduce it just fine, and was entirely correct in doing so (`0` by itself is an `int` literal, therefore any type deduced from literal `0` is `int`).  Since this isn't the intended behaviour, `T{0}` is thus used to create a `T` literal instead of an `int` literal, allowing the types to be deduced as `T`.

Comment: The actual problem, though, was in line 6; it seems MSVC crashes when using a compound assignment operator with a floating-point value on the right side and an integer type (`char` types, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, and their `unsigned` counterparts) variable on the left side, while within a `constexpr` function being executed at compile time; the behaviour can be replicated with a function like `constexpr int func() { int i = 0; i += 1.f; return i; }`, by using it to initialise a `constexpr` variable such as `constexpr int i = func();`  Weirdly, `i = i + 1.f;` doesn't trigger this.

Comment: [Clang also considers this to be invalid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e37ec5feffdf39f2), emitting a "constexpr variable 'i' must be initialized by a constant expression" error for line 2, on the grounds that sub-expression `i += 1.f;` isn't valid in a constant expression.  I'm not 100% sure, but I believe this is because converting a floating-point value to an integer type is a narrowing conversion.  I'm not sure why that disqualifies `i += 1.f`, but not `i = 1.f` or `i = i + 1.f`, however.